# Element is no longer attached to the DOM selenium

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have the following problem with my Selenium in Ruby. It generates the error, that the element is no longer attached to the DOM. I found some solutions to wait, but I wasn`t able to figure out if I can wait for an element which has no ID. Can i wait for an element if I only have the className?

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
#require Firefox installation !!

browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
browser.get <URL>

wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 20)

js_code = "return document.getElementsByClassName('Cell ')"

rawdata = Array.new
puts rawdata.size

elements = browser.execute_script(js_code)
elements.each{|e| rawdata.push(e.text) }

puts rawdata.size
arrSize = rawdata.length


puts rawdata.at(5) + " " + rawdata.at(4) + " " + rawdata.at(9) + " " + rawdata.at(6)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answers your question but not necessarily resolves your exception. If it doesn't, you might want to post HTML snippets and stacktrace.

Here is how to use WebDriverWait in Ruby:

```
# create wait like you have already done
wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 20)

# wait until something, you can use any locators you want, not just ids
# don't inject JavaScript directly, unless you have to
wait.until { driver.find_element(:class => "dojoxGridCell") }

# do stuff to your raw data
```